# Скачивание файлов. VK API. Какая должна быть задержка?

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, kotlin

Какую надо ставить минимальную задержку массовом скачивании файлов в ВК?

Заметил, если не написать Thread.sleep(), ВК может закрыть соединение.
Сейчас использую такой код:

```
    // Парсим JSON, сохраняем имена файлов и ссылки...

    // Download files
    docList.forEach { doc ->
        val url = URL(doc.url)
        val file = File(savePath + doc.title)

        try {
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file)
            logTextArea?.appendText("Completed: ${file.path}\n")

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            logTextArea?.appendText("Error: ${file.path}\n")
        }

        Thread.sleep(200)
    }
```

Хотелось бы свести sleep к минимуму.
Подскажите, может такой подход вообще не правильный?

*Пример написан на Kotlin но, думаю, это не столь важно.

Answer (score 0):

У API вконтакте есть ограничение, так что слишком часто делать запросы не получится:

> К методам API ВКонтакте (за исключением методов из секций secure и ads) с ключом доступа пользователя можно обращаться не чаще 3 раз в секунду.

См. "Ограничения и рекомендации" https://vk.com/dev/api_requests